# How to discard lines in text file until certain string is found

Tags: java, text-files, readline

The file begins with about 200 lines of background information that i don't need. Im trying to skip/ignore those 200 lines until a string is found. Once this string is found I want to be able to continue processing the rest of the text file.

Sample Text File:
(up to around line 240 is all the lines i need to skip/ignore) 
http://pastebin.com/5Ay4ad6y

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String endOfSyllabus = "~ End of Syllabus";
    Path objPath = Paths.get("2014HamTechnician.txt");

    if (Files.exists(objPath)) {
        File objFile = objPath.toFile();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile))) {
            String line = in.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                line = in.readLine();
            }

            if(endOfSyllabus.equals(line) ){

           restOfTextFile = line.split(endOfSyllabus);
         }

         }

        System.out.println(restOfTextFile[0]);




        }
    catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
    else{

        System.out.println(
              objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
    }



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new A19015_Form().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem you are seeing with your current code ?

Comment: With the line `if(line == endOfSyllabus ){`: Don't use `==` in Java to compare `String` values; use `String#equals` instead.

Comment: That `while` loop will not work well when you reach end of file.

Comment: I guess the problem is how would I be able to discard all those lines so I can continue to extract data from the text file. I want to be able to loop through the text file processing each line, but first I want to discard all the lines before the `~ End of Syllabus` string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you know the exact string that you are looking

```
if (lineString.startsWith("insert exact string")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
boolean found = false;
for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null;) {
    found = found || line.equals(endOfSyllabus); 
    if (found) {
         // process line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("test.txt"));
        List<String> avLines = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean valid = false;
        for (String line : lines) {

            if (line.trim().equals("~ End of Syllabus")) {
                valid = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (valid) {
                avLines.add("\n"+line);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(avLines.size());

    }

}
```

Comment: well I tried this: http://pastebin.com/4rDpLfrM . I get an out of bounds now and it doesn't display the rest of the text file.

Comment: Have you tried the code I have displayed? Could you tell me exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I don' t understand how to extract specific data from a text file. The way I have to do it is a bit complex. For example, I want to make a Test Generator. The questions and answers are in the text file (http://pastebin.com/5Ay4ad6y). I want to parse the text file and create a database record for each question.